# Spawning multiple processes from PHP command-line script

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have custom build system written in PHP. It's similar to **make** tool, gathering source files with dependencies to compile and link them.

It uses **system** function to run G++, like this:

```
    system("g++ -c $file -o $out");
```

It's working great. However I have a multi-core processor and I would like to use those extra cores to speed up the process (like **make -j 8**). How can I do it in PHP? I don't need to have multithreading in PHP per se, I just need to spawn few child processes and wait for them to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since that is usually built-in for PHPs CLI version, you can use [`pcntl_fork()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php). It duplicates the current PHP process into a child, which can then work separately from the parent process.

See the example on the manual page.

(You could also utilize [PEAR System_Daemon](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon) which encapsulates that functionality; though it does a bit too much for your case.)